# Is it possible to get same test accuracy for different classification models?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have ran a number of basic classification models with default options using the following logic:

```
# setup the basic models with all arguments as default
et_clf = ExtraTreesClassifier()
svc_clf = SVC()
knn_clf = KNeighborsClassifier()
log_clf = LogisticRegression()
dt_clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
rnd_clf = RandomForestClassifier()

# import accuracy_score
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score

# use a for-loop to compute the test set accuracy for each classifier
for clf in (et_clf, svc_clf, knn_clf, log_clf, dt_clf, rnd_clf ):
    clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
    y_pred = clf.predict(X_test)
    print(clf.__class__.__name__, accuracy_score(y_test, y_pred))
```

The test accuracy for ExtraTreesClassifier, SVC, KNeighborsClassifier and LogisticRegression is exactly the same:

```
ExtraTreesClassifier 0.8517915309446255
SVC 0.8517915309446255
KNeighborsClassifier 0.8517915309446255
LogisticRegression 0.8517915309446255
DecisionTreeClassifier 0.46416938110749184
RandomForestClassifier 0.8078175895765473
```

Is this even possible?

Comment: It most certainly is, especially if your test set is relatively small. How many test samples do you have?

Comment: You can try inspecting which samples are being misclassified. It might be that all misclassified samples belong to the same class. Also, you can try to perturb a little the samples with some noise and see if the accuracies remain the same. It can also be a problem of number of samples, as @desertnaut suggested.

Comment: There are 614 samples. Good suggestion to add some noise to see if accuracies remain the same. Thanks

Comment: You can try to use cross-validation

Comment: I find it very strange to ask "is this even possible", when your question has the same evidence that shows that indeed, it is possible.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible, depends on your dataset size. To check whether models give accuracy correct, add imbalance data in your dataset and run all models again.

Comment: Adding imbalanced data in the dataset and running **all** (!) models again just for ensuring that the accuracy is correct is extremely poor advice .

Comment: Sometimes you need some other metrics depending on your problem; like *precision* and *recall*, you can not rely on accuracy everytime, especially when the data is imbalanced.